# How to set the system property max.retries in thucydides

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, thucydides

I need to set the system property max.retries in thucydides. I need to rerun the failed test again in thucydides so that can be done by using max.retries. Can any one please guide me in this regard

Answer (score 0):

Did you try setting it this way ?

```
    System.setProperty("max.retries", 3);
```

Comment: Hi Dharma, I tried but its not working. I am working on this for last 2 days. I came to know that only executing from maven we can rerun the failed test cases in thucydides.